# java: interfaces and templates

Tags: java, generics, casting

This doesn't seem to work (compiler complains that `Something`'s `getFoo()` method doesn't implement `HasFoo`) and I can't figure out why or how to fix it....

```
enum FooKey { BLOB1, DONUT, ... }

interface HasFoo
{
   public Object getFoo(FooKey k);
}

class Something implements HasFoo
{
    private Map<FooKey, Object> map;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    <T> T getFoo(FooKey k)
    {
        return (T)map.get(k);
    }

    /* other stuff deleted */
}
```

I want both an interface and I also want to be able to do stuff like

```
Something something = ...
Blob blob1 = something.getFoo(FooKey.BLOB1);
Donut donut = something.getFoo(FooKey.DONUT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
interface HasFoo
{
   public <T> T getFoo(FooKey k);
}
```

Comment: doh! So it does! I didn't know you could do that in an interface, I thought you could only do `interface HasFoo<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override a non-generic method with a generic one. An alternative could be:

```
interface HasFoo
{
    <T> T getFoo(FooKey k);
}

class Something implements HasFoo
{
    private Map<FooKey, Object> map;

    @Override
    public <T> T getFoo(FooKey k)
    {
        return (T)map.get(k);
    }

    /* other stuff deleted */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler's error really mean that methods' signatures differ:

```
<T> T getFoo(FooKey k)

Object getFoo(FooKey k)
```

Althought Object is the ultimate ancestor compiler wants signatures to be exactly same

Answer (score 0):

Your interface is specifying an Object, whereas the return type of the impl is 'anything'.  You need to change the interface to return T.

BTW, you could also declare your map to be <FooKey, T>

Comment: can't declare the map to be <FooKey, T>. T is not constant for the class. it's a map of different things.

Comment: yes, you can.  you're returning T from the method...which is coming from the map, no?